# Are each of the following statements for chords, radiuses, diameters and arcs of a circle true?

Tags: geometry, circles

Are each of the following statements for a circle true?

1. If a radius bisects a chord, then this radius is perpendicular to this chord.
2. If a radius is perpendicular to a chord, then this radius bisects this chord.
3. If a radius bisects a chord, then this radius bisects a corresponding arc.
4. If a radius bisects a arc, then this radius bisects a corresponding chord.
5. If a radius is perpendicular to a chord, then this radius bisects a corresponding arc.
6. If a radius bisects a arc, then this radius is perpendicular to a corresponding chord.

Are each of these statements true for a diameter instead of the radius?

What if the chord is a diameter? Are each of these statements true in this case?

Answer (score 0):

They are definitely all true. Any straight line going through the center of the circle has to be perpendicular to a chord if it bisects it. To bisect it, after all, it must split it into two equal parts. This works for diameters as well, yes. Most of these situations follow the same logic as others.

I suggest drawing chords and seeing if you can create a radius that is not perpendicular to them but must also split them into equal parts. It is impossible, I guarantee (unless you draw ovals or some other shapes).

Comment: In a circle the chord has 2 corresponding arcs (minor and major). Bisects a diameter both these arcs?

What about my last question? Looks like, if the chord is a diameter, then statements 1 and 3 are false.

That's why I've asked this question on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yes a diameter that bisects a chord must be perpendicular to both the chord and the major and minor arc. Just look at examples like I said if you are skeptical.

Comment: If the chord is a diameter, then a radius/diameter bisects this chord at any (not only right) angle and divides the corresponding arc/arcs into 2 any (not only equal) parts.

Comment: How would a radii/diameter run through the center of a circle and a chord without being perpendicular to the chord? I'd like a proof/intuitive example.

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/09q29.png, where AB is a chord; OC is a radius; O is a center of a circle; AB, AC, CB are arcs. AO is equal to OB. AC is not equal to CB. OC is not perpendicular to AB.

See also https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBQCk.png, where AB is a chord; CD is a diameter; O is a center of a circle; AB, AC, CB, AD, DB are arcs. AO is equal to OB. AC is not equal to CB, AD is not equal to DB. CD is not perpendicular to AB.

Comment: You know, I thought those were good examples originally then I rejected it because I noticed the lines had width to them. The width made me think it did not bisect it (notice how if the lines were much thicker the diameter would not be able to bisect it at that angle). Yeah assuming the diameter/radius is a true line in the sense that it has no width, it would not have to perpendicular.